# Действия по расписанию

Tags: android

Встречаюсь с этим в андроиде в первый раз. Нужно реализовать сервис. Который будет совершать в определенное время определенные действия. Т.е допустим сегодня в 17:56 выдать оповещение о том-то, завтра в 18:39 что-либо еше. Реально ли реализовать такое? Если да то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте подходящий для вас метод из семейства set из класса [`AlarmManager`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Сервис для этого не обязателен.